# How to get id like "invokedOn" text by a right click event with Bootstrap ContextMenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

I am using Bootstrap 3.0 ContextMenu. here is a link http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/X9tgY/

I need to know how i can get the id or data-Id of the clicked element. i try many of the tricks but i cant get the clicked element id? Like when i clicked on "Jacob" row i get the "Jacob" after clicked. I also need from this line
`<td data-id="user-3">
   <a data-id="user-3">Jacob<a/>
 <td/>` 
"data-Id"?

i tried  `var $selectedFileId = $(this).closest('a').html();` or  `alert($(this).parent('a').html());`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for get clicked element id

```
jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
console.log(e.target.id);
})
```

Comment: you right harutyun but dude from this i can get the id of Menu item not from the data. i need the id of the row where i click on my page item?

Answer (score 0):

I get the id by little additions in the contextMenu handler, Changes

```
// click handler for context menu
function ContextMenuClickHandler() {
    $(settings.menuSelector)
     .off('click')
     .on('click', function (e) {
      $(this).hide();

       var $invokedOn = $(this).data("invokedOn");
       var $selectedMenu = $(e.target);
       // My Changes
       var $selectedFileId = $(this).data("invokedOn").find('.yourClass').attr('id');

       settings.menuSelected.call($(this), $invokedOn, $selectedMenu, $selectedFileId);
    });
}
```